# How to run a program for each line in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file such as file.txt:

```
Specie1
Specie2
Specie3
```

and I have a program to run on these 3 species, it is called `bedtools getfasta`

So the idea I had was to do:

```
cat file_species.txt |
while read line; do 
    bedtools getfasta -fi /path/${line}/${line}.fa -bed /path/${line}/Recover_fasta.bed -s -fo /path/${line}/Fasta_loci_seq.fa" ;
done
```

If I do an `echo` I get:

```
bedtools getfasta -fi /path/Specie1/Specie1.fa -bed /path/Specie1/Recover_fasta.bed -s -fo /path/Specie1/Fasta_loci_seq.fa" ;
done
bedtools getfasta -fi /path/Specie2/Specie2.fa -bed /path/Specie1/Recover_fasta.bed -s -fo /path/Specie1/Fasta_loci_seq.fa" ;
done
bedtools getfasta -fi /path/Specie3/Specie3.fa -bed /path/Specie1/Recover_fasta.bed -s -fo /path/Specie1/Fasta_loci_seq.fa" ;
done
```

and if I just past these codes its works, but how can I just execute it in my first script after `"do"` instead of doing an echo and then paste the codes?

Comment: Can you show how you did the echo?  If you did it right, just removing the word echo is probably all you need.

Comment: Maybe remove that trailing semicolon since there's a newline there already.

Comment: Oh yes it was juste because of the (") sorry

Comment: There is a single doublequote (so it is just opening a quoted scope) in the line with `bedtools`.  This will not run at all.  Please provide the real code you are testing with.

Comment: You should also really replace `${line}` with `"$line"`

Comment: Note that instead of a loop you can use `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the trailing double-quote and semicolon at the end, and replace `${line}` with `"$line"` :

```
cat file_species.txt |
while read line; do 
    bedtools getfasta -fi /path/"$line"/"$line".fa -bed /path/"$line"/Recover_fasta.bed -s -fo /path/"$line"/Fasta_loci_seq.fa
done
```